# Website not showing in Google Chrome on Phone

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have 2 version of a table I want to show, depending on the device. It all works fine on desktop but on mobile, I can't get the table to show using google chrome.. it does work with samsung internet though. I have an S9.. but i've tested it on a note 8 as well as it doesn't work.

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong.  The webpage is https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/sea-point/

The CSS is -

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    table.table_seapoint{
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -50px;
 text-align: center;
}
    table.table_seapoint_mobile
    {display: none;}

}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {

    table.table_seapoint{
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -50px;
}
    table.table_seapoint_mobile
    {display: none;}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 770px) and (orientation : portrait) {
table.table_seapoint_mobile{
  margin-top: -50px;
    width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
margin-bottom: -60px;
}
    table.table_seapoint {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

HTML is -

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<table class="table_seapoint">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td rowspan="10"><img src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/test_image.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="219" /></td>
<td colspan="4">
<h1 style="font-weight: lighter;">STUNNING LUXUARY FLOWER BOUQUETS</h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<h1 style="font-weight: lighter;">FRESHLY CUT AND HAND DELIVERED</h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<h1 style="font-weight: lighter;">IN SEA POINT AND</h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<h1 style="font-weight: lighter;">ACROSS THE WESTERN CAPE</h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img class="valign size-full wp-image-4337" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/greentick.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="25" /></td>
<td style="padding-left: 10px;" colspan="3">BEST PRICE PROMISE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 10px;" colspan="3">100% MONEY BACK GUARANTEE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4337" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/greentick.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="25" /></td>
<td style="padding-left: 10px;" colspan="3">QUICK AND EASY ONLINE ORDERING</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4337" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/greentick.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="25" /></td>
<td style="padding-left: 10px;" colspan="3">24/7 CUSTOMER SUPPORT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4337" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/greentick.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="25" /></td>
<td style="padding-left: 10px;" colspan="3">HAPPINESS ASSURED</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<h1 style="font-weight: lighter;">ORDER BEFORE 12PM FOR NEXT DAY DELIVERY</h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4385" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/phone-1.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="25" /></td>
<td style="padding-left: 10px;" nowrap="nowrap"><b> 079 885 9609 </b></td>
<td style="padding-left: 30px;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4386" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/envelope-1.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="25" /></td>
<td style="padding-left: 10px;"><b> hello@flowersforeveryone.co.za </b></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="table_seapoint_mobile">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="4"><img src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/test_image.jpg" alt="" width="60%" height="60%" /> :</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="4">
<h1 style="font-weight: lighter;">STUNNING LUXUARY FLOWER BOUQUETS</h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="4">
<h1 style="font-weight: lighter;">FRESHLY CUT AND HAND DELIVERED</h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 7px;" colspan="4">
<h1 style="font-weight: lighter;">IN SEA POINT AND ACROSS THE WESTERN CAPE</h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 40px;" colspan="4"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4337" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/greentick.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="25" />
BEST PRICE PROMISE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 40px;" colspan="4"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4337" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/greentick.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="25" />
MONEY BACK GUARANTEE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 40px;" colspan="4"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4337" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/greentick.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="25" />
QUICK AND EASY ONLINE ORDERING</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 40px;" colspan="4"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4337" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/greentick.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="25" />
24/7 CUSTOMER SUPPORT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 40px;" colspan="4"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4337" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/greentick.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="25" />
HAPPINESS ASSURED</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<h1 style="font-weight: lighter;">ORDER BEFORE 12PM FOR NEXT DAY DELIVERY</h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="4"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4337" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/phone-1.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="25" />079 885 9609</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="4"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4337" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/envelope-1.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="25" /><b>hello@flowersforeveryone.co.za</b></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="stuff">[recent_products per_page="3" columns="3" orderby="title" order="ASC" paginate="true" category="featured" width=300px]</div>
```

UPDATE - I have changed the CSS to the below - but it still doesn't work -

```
@media (max-width: 599px) { 
table.table_seapoint_mobile{
  margin-top: -50px;
    width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
margin-bottom: -60px;
}
    table.table_seapoint {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
table.table_seapoint_mobile{
  margin-top: -50px;
    width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
margin-bottom: -60px;
}
    table.table_seapoint {
        display: none;
    }   
}


@media (min-width: 900px) {
table.table_seapoint{
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -50px;
}
    table.table_seapoint_mobile
    {display: none;}

}

 @media (min-width: 1200px) { table.table_seapoint{
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -50px;
}
    table.table_seapoint_mobile
    {display: none;}

}

  @media (min-width: 1800px) { 
        table.table_seapoint{
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -50px;
}
    table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@mixin for-phone-only {
  @media (max-width: 599px) { @content; }
}
@mixin for-tablet-portrait-up {
  @media (min-width: 600px) { @content; }
}
@mixin for-tablet-landscape-up {
  @media (min-width: 900px) { @content; }
}
@mixin for-desktop-up {
  @media (min-width: 1200px) { @content; }
}
@mixin for-big-desktop-up {
  @media (min-width: 1800px) { @content; }
}
```

by https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-100-correct-way-to-do-css-breakpoints-88d6a5ba1862/

Try some of these media queries instead.

using the portrait media query is pretty glitchy, and I wouldn't use it.

Comment: Okay so I should say this? - (at)mixin for-phone-only {
  @media (max-width: 599px) { 
table.table_seapoint_mobile{
  margin-top: -50px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
margin-bottom: -60px;
}
 table.table_seapoint {
  display: none;
 }
}
}      I put them in my CSS customiser in wordpress... but it says unknown rule... it still doesn't work

Comment: no you only put @media(){} but use the min-width settings given

Comment: the problems you have are because you are using "and portrait"

Comment: Okay.. I've updated the CSS code.. please see the update in the question.. but it still doesn't work

Comment: hmmm. it's working fine for me. the only thing im experiencing is a second table on a certain breakpoint, but it is a duplicate of the same table.

Comment: Is it working on Chrome on a mobile device? It's still not showing either table on mine. Is there another way to do this? I essentially want the same information, but it needs to be formatted differently for mobile due to space issues

Comment: try removing display:none; and change the display one by one, to find the breakpoint that is messing it up, so you can target correctly.

Comment: Ooohh it's fixed!! Thank you!!! I noticed that when I did remove display:none i could see something on my phone.. but when I put it back nothing changed. So i disabled and enabled the google app and it's fixed! Can I ask another quick question please... if you look down the bottom you'll see the pagination goes on top of the "best quality" image... how do I stop that from happening? Thanks so much!!

Comment: That's a very difficult thing to answer. I would suggest reviewing all your positioning and sizing aspects of all elements on your page. I notice lsx-pagnation-wrapper is using margin-top, and is using "rem" measurement. Be sure that all other sizing properties within the same nest use the same type of measurement, so it is easy to code responsively.